# Spring Batch: What is the way to pass a huge Map Object across the Job in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Use case:
Step 1:
ItemReader : Reading Data from Database in chunk of 1000
ItemProcessor : Process those Data.
ItemWriter : Write the data in a Map for used in next step

Step 2:
ItemReader : Reading the Map
ItemProcessor : Process the Map data and get the new object.
ItemWriter : Persist the new process object in database.

Now I want the Map the should remain same across the job,
Currently I have created a different POJO class for Map and Autowired in the step to use it, but the problem is when ever I new chunk of data loading my Map is reseting but I want to keep the Map object with all its value as it is across the Job execution.

Comment: Could you add the code to the question?

Comment: How big is "huge"?

Comment: @MichaelMinella..its a huge key, value pair that's why I not using JobExecutionContext, because in some other place I have read that its not a good practice to set a huge dataset inside JobExecutionContext.

Answer (score 0):

Try with StepExecutionListener.